# Матрица перспективной проекции

Tags: javascript, матрицы

Добрый день. Я нашел на данном источнике: http://gamesmaker.ru/programming/directx/virtualnaya-kamera-perspektivnaya-proekciya/ информацию о том, как задать матрицу перспективной проекции по field of vision Y, ближайшей и дальней границах обзора. Это всё конечно замечательно, но я никак не могу понять, как из данных аргументов вычленить ширину плоскости на которую проектируются объекты?
Я работаю с WebGL и в шейдере использую матрицу перспективной проекции, но вот никак не пойму, какая ширина плоскости.

Лично у меня проблема в том, что при клике мыши на экран, мне нужно понять в какой точке (глобально) был произведен клик. Я конечно же могу найти в процентах расстояние от центра экрана, но на какую величину умножить дальше - я не знаю, так как не знаю ширину плоскости проекции. И нужно ли для этого отнимать глубину проекции. Извиняюсь заранее за плохо сформулированный вопрос, надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операция проецирования необратима, поскольку делает из трех измерений два (пользователь же не указывает "глубину" при клике мышью?)

Чтобы определить, куда пользователь кликнул - надо перебрать активные объекты, спроецировать их на экран - и посмотреть, попадает ли этот клик в область силуэта объекта.

Иногда для решения этой задачи создают скрытую поверхность, на которой рисуют активные объекты без освещения и хитрых шейдеров, каждый объект - своим цветом. Потом по цвету пикселя можно определить на какой объект пользователь кликнул.